# Textmate: Auto indenting long line of PHP code

Tags: php, textmate

In Textmate, I may have one really long line of PHP code that will wrap into 2+ lines due to my window width:

```
echo 'This may be a long line of code, which will wrap to multiple lines depending on the width of the browser window...';
```

I noticed that adding `//` to the end of the line will make it auto-indent any multiple lines underneath the first, so that it looks nicer.

```
echo 'This may be a long line of code, which will wrap to multiple
    lines depending on the width of the browser window...'; //
```

How can I make this behavior automatic (not having to put `//` at the end of almost every line of code I write), and how can I add this same formatting to other code libraries, such as HTML, CSS and SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try View->Soft Wrap or View->Wrap Columns?

You should try to not have super long strings in your code because it makes it hard to read for other people (especially those that put their monitors 90 degrees). A lot of times, if I have to have a super long string in the PHP like that, I'll do something like this:

```
echo 'This may be a long line of code, which will wrap to multiple '
     . 'lines depending on the width of the browser window...';
```

And if I need to put a bunch of text into a variable for some reason, like a raw SQL query:

```
$query = 'SELECT id, name, other_column, this_property, something_else '
       . 'FROM really_long_table_name_for_no_reason '
       . 'WHERE other_column IN ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'] '
       . 'AND this_property = 7 '
       . 'AND something_else = 'nine_why_not' '
       . 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30,90';
```